# How to append data to h5 file in python?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I would like to add more and more data to the HDF5 file as the data comes in. I tried the following: First create a dataset with first array and then try to add one more value to the h5 file by resizing it.

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 87, 2, 3, 5, 12, 14, 16]).astype(int)
y = 9
path = "out.h5"
with h5py.File(path, "a") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset("somedata", data=x, maxshape=(None,))
    dset[:] = y
    print(dset.shape)

    for i in range(3):
        dset.resize(dset.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        dset["somedata"] = y

some = h5py.File("out.h5", "r")
for x in some["somedata"]:
    print(x)
```

But it is throwing me an error:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 582, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("Illegal slicing argument (not a compound dataset)")
TypeError: Illegal slicing argument (not a compound dataset)
```

Comment: Why are you using `dset["somedata"]`?   `dset` is the dataset object.  You used it correctly with `dset[:]=y`.  I think `some["somedata"]` is correct.

Comment: I'd imagine the easiest way is using pandas's `df.to_hdf` with `mode='a'`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html

Comment: @hpaulj it worked with following: `dset[-1:] = y`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to resize the dataset and overwrite it with `y`. Can you try this?

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 87, 2, 3, 5, 12, 14, 16]).astype(int)
y = 9
path = "out.h5"
with h5py.File(path, "a") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset('somedata', data=x, maxshape=(None,))
    dset[:] = y
    print(dset.shape)

    for i in range(3):
        dset.resize(dset.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        dset[:] = y

with h5py.File("out.h5", "r") as some:
    for x in some["somedata"]:
        print(x)
```